# scroll issue, have to move cursor or click elsewhere to scroll into another element

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a situation and I have to use different full screen sized, scrollable div, and in each div, there are enough content that we have to scroll to see that.
So, the problem is when I reach to end by scrolling in any div, then to scroll in next div or previous div I have to move cursor or click elsewhere to transfer control of scrolling.
and then I can scroll in other element.

so, in my webpage, I can't scroll at once and see all the content of all div.
please https://codepen.io/mayur_patel78/pen/MWVYjgX

so, I want to scroll at once without clicking anywhere or moving cursor and go through all div.'s content. it is a normal behavior of the scrolling, but I want to fix it like this way.
please suggest me or help me if you have faced this kind of problem or you have solution regarding this.
Thanks in advance for help!!

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="div1"><div style="height:5000px"></div></div>
        <div class="div2"><div style="height:5000px"></div></div>
        <div class="div3"><div style="height:5000px"></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

style file

```
.container {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    /* can't put specific height of a webpage */
    height: auto;
}

.div1, .div2, .div3 {
    /* we will have enough content inside each fullscreen size div 
     so that we have to scroll inside each div to see all the content */
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.div1 {background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);}
.div2 {background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);}
.div3 {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `overflow: hidden`? You can also decrease the height of `div1`,  `div2`, `div3`

Comment: where are you suggesting to use ```overflow: hidden```, in parent of all div, or in each div ?

Comment: use that property in each div

Comment: I wanted to go through all sections/divs as I scroll, but it stops scrolling when it reach to end of any one section/div, then I have to move cursor or click elsewhere  and then I am able to scroll into next element/div.  I hope you got the issue

Comment: it will hide all contents inside all div. I don't want to do that. I want to show all the content

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector('div')  
myDiv.addEventListener('scroll', () => {  
  if (myDiv.offsetHeight + myDiv.scrollTop >= myDiv.scrollHeight) {  
    myDiv.classList.add = "overflow-hidden"  
  }else{
     myDiv.classList.remove = "overflow-hidden" 
  }
})
```

You can add class `overflow-hidden` when the div has reached the end and in else case you can remove the class.

Obviously you have to get all the div with a specific id maybe and run the above function, I leave that part to you. :)

Comment: Hi, I got your solution, but it did not worked, when it reached to end of the particular section, scrolling just stopped as before.

Comment: for further scrolling through other divisions, I have to move cursor here and there then it fetches other element and starts scrolling in that element

Comment: Did it added the overflow-hidden class?

Comment: yes, I have added that class with ```overflow: hidden``` property.

Comment: This is the only generic solution for your problem that I can think. :(